# UWP Sockets: client socket StoreAsync operation not interrupted on socket close

Tags: sockets, networking, uwp

With UWP sockets on Windows 10, I'm seeing an annoying behavior with pending asynchronous write operations not being interrupted when `CancelIOAsync` or `Dispose` is called on the socket. Below is some sample code that demonstrates the issue.

Basically, the while loop loops for 2 iterations until the send socket buffer is full (the server side connection doesn't read the data on purpose to demonstrate the problem). The next `await socket.StoreAsync()` operation ends up waiting indefinitely, it's not interrupted by the closing of the socket.

Any ideas on how to interrupt the pending `StoreAsync`?

Thanks
Benoit.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
private StreamSocket socket;
private StreamSocket serverSocket;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    StreamSocketListener listener = new StreamSocketListener();
    listener.ConnectionReceived += OnConnection;
    listener.Control.KeepAlive = false;
    listener.BindServiceNameAsync("12345").GetResults();
}

async private void Connect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    socket = new StreamSocket();
    socket.Control.KeepAlive = false;
    await socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName("localhost"), "12345");
    DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            writer.WriteBytes(new byte[1000000]);
            await writer.StoreAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine("sent bytes");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("sent failed : " + ex.ToString());
    }
}

async private void Close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //
    // Closing the client connection with a pending write doesn't cancel the pending write.
    //
    Debug.WriteLine("Closing Client Connection");
    await socket.CancelIOAsync();
    socket.Dispose();
}

private void OnConnection(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received connection");
    serverSocket = args.Socket;
}
}
```

Comment: When you call `writer.StoreAsync()` method, please try to call `dataWriter.DetachStream()` method. You could see the official code sample:https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/DataReaderWriter/cs/Scenario1_WriteReadStream.xaml.cs#L89

Comment: `In order to prolong the lifetime of the stream, detach it from the DataWriter so that it will not be closed when Dispose() is called on dataWriter. Were we to fail to detach the stream, the call to dataWriter.Dispose() would close the underlying stream, preventing its subsequent use by the DataReader below.`